# Dealing with new outliers after capping

Tags: data-mining, data-cleaning, outlier

I'm trying to cap outliers in a column of my pandas DataFrame.
Here's the boxplot for a column of my original data.
[image: boxplot for a column of my original data]
So, using code from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420114/11814996), I tried capping outliers.

Here's how capped column looks like, with new outliers after upper bound.
[image: only with outliers at upper bound capped]

My problem now is, I can't keep capping outliers, yes! What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once is all it takes; you're done. The point of dealing with outliers is that they are *rare*. Forcing your model to fit to those outliers can make its performance against inliers (which it will encounter far more often) worse, and that's A Bad Thing. Although you now have values that *look* like outliers when you plot them, this is an artifact of your earlier transformation - those values should be within the "normal" expected range of values for your data.